# Asp.NET Webresources with better URL

Tags: asp.net, webresource

it is possible to write own "webresources provider" in asp.net to change webresources URL which looks like:

> WebResource.axd?d=qoS8iGdUsV4f8NgR_HS-hHWgRO2CDfStRaaqn7oJ2xBuwIMbn27JNufuUMn-aVlK0&
>   t=634013997250859375"

to e.g.:

> /webresources/folder/script.js

?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I could realize, you are after to change this behavior for all of controls (included already existed controls) which is impossible unless override their behavior. Most web controls use embedded resources and do not support custom script path.

ASP.NET uses `AssemblyResourceLoader` to handle `.axd` requests and `Page.ClientScript.GetWebResourceUrl()` that should be used to get the WebResource path, uses `AssemblyResourceLoader.GetWebResourceUrl()` internally. You can not change the `ClientScriptManager` behavior. Whereas `ClientScriptManager` class is seald and `Page.ClientScript` does not have setter accessor and is not overridable.